# "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero" error when there isn't really math involved?

Tags: java, events, event-listener

This is my code so far - I am trying to use WidgetViewer to take in details of a certain Event and print it out on a JTextArea.
However, I'm having trouble doing so - there are no errors in the code itself but when I run it, I get countless lines of exceptions, with the top line being:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero.

I have an Event class in another file, FYI. No errors there.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Interface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WidgetViewer wv = new WidgetViewer();
        
        JLabel eventName = new JLabel("Event Name");
        wv.add(eventName, 10, 30, 300, 20);
        
        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        wv.add(name, 10, 50, 300, 20);
        //Similar for the rest of JTextFields and JLabels
        
        JButton create = new JButton("Create an Event");
        wv.add(create, 10, 320, 300, 20);
        
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea("");
        wv.add(text, 10, 460, 900, 20);
        
        create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Event event1 = new Event();
                String eventName = name.getText();
                String eventVenue = venue.getText();
                int venueCapacity = Integer.parseInt(capacity.getText());
                String eventDate = date.getText();
                int ticketsSold = Integer.parseInt(sold.getText());
                int ticketPrice = Integer.parseInt(price.getText());
                int overhead = Integer.parseInt(costs.getText());
                
                text.setText("Event " + event1.getEventName() + ", Venue: " + event1.getEventVenue() + ", Date: " + 
                event1.getDate() + ", Tickets Sold: " + event1.getTicketsSold() + ", Ticket Price: " + 
                event1.getTicketPrice() + ", Overhead: " + event1.getOverhead() + ", Venue Capacity: " + event1.getVenueCapacity() + ", Profit: " + event1.getProfit() +
                        "Break Even Point = " + event1.getBreakEvenPoint());
                
            }
        });    
        
    }

}
```

The exceptions are:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Event.getBreakEvenPoint(Event.java:55)
    at Interface$1.actionPerformed(Interface.java:73)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: The exception tells you exactly in what class and on what line the exception occurs. Please add that information.

Comment: Your `actionPerformed()` method looks strange. You create an (empty) `Event` object, load a lot of values into local variables and then (presumably) query the `Event` object for those values...

Comment: I added the exceptions to the post. Also, I did that because I wasn't quite sure how to go about what I need - I am trying to get the inputs from the textfields and print them out on the textarea while also create a new Event with the information from the textfields.

Comment: If you want to "_create a new Event with the information from the textfields_" then you should do that: remove the line `Event event1 = new Event();` and add a line `Event event1 = new Event(eventName, eventVenue, venueCapacity, eventDate, ticketsSold, ticketPrice, overhead);`. You also need to add a constructor to the `Event` class that takes all these parameters and assigns the parameter values to the fields of the `Event` class.

Comment: *I added the exceptions to the post* - so what don't you understand about the exceptions? It tells you the statement (55) that is causing the problem. Your Event class is a custom class so you look at the statement in that class to see what your code is doing. You have a divide by 0 Exception. That tells you the properties in your class have not been assigned a valid value. We can't debug your code because we don't have access to your class. You either need to add a constructor to your class to set all the values when you create the Event, or you need "setter" methods to set each property.

Comment: Thomas Kläger's comment solved everything! I do have the constructor in my `Event` class. Thank you all for your help!